# Is this proved is correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please help me

*Do I have Proving is true?*

Question ->
  Prove:

(C-A)$\cup$(B-A)=(C$\cap$B)-A

My Proving:

(C-A)$\cup$(B-A)=((C$\cap$A')$\cup$ (B$\cap$A')

=(C$\cup$B)$\cap$A'

=(C$\cup$B)-A'

*Do you think my Proving is correct?*

Comment: Did you mean $(C\setminus A)\cup(B\setminus A)=(C\cup B)\setminus A$, with a union on the righthand side? If you did, your argument is correct.

Comment: Echoing Brian's comment, the right hand side of your first equation has $\cap$ instead of $\cup$.

Comment: I mean, this is exactly
(C-A) ∪ (B-A) = (C ∩ B)-A

Comment: No, it needs to be $(C-A)\cup (B-A)=(C\cup B)-A$

Comment: Is the wrong question?

Comment: @flashdesign: The answer you did should be as Brian said. So if you have $(C\cap B)-A$, the answer might be wrong or have a typo in printing.

Comment: It is true.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $(C-A)\cup (B-A)=(C \cap A')\cup (B \cap A')$ which is $ (C \cup B) \cap A'$ and it equals to $(C \cup B)-A$ not $(C \cup B)-A'$

Comment: Yes exactly
Thanks for your very complete Answer :)

Comment: +1 Helpful...and I'll keep my look-out, per your request!

Comment: very elegant answer

Comment: By the way: good mornin', Babak!

Comment: We had snow yesterday. Quite a bit! Kind of a slow night tonight again. But that's okay. You had a nice day again yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

hint:

(C−A)∪(B−A)=(C∩A ′ )∪(B∩A ′ )

(C∪B)∩A ′ = (C∪B)−A  not (C∪B)−A ′